# Why does it hang indefinitely?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, infinite-loop

I wonder why is the reason why this code never finishes its execution.

It makes use of [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)

```
void Main()
{
    var values = MoreEnumerable.Random(1, 200);
    var filtered = MyMethod(values)
    .Take(2)
    .Dump();
}

public IEnumerable<int> MyMethod(IEnumerable<int> source) 
{
    return source
    .Select(x => new[] { x })
    .Aggregate((a, b) => new[] { a.Last() + b.First()});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `MoreEnumerable.Random(1, 200)` returns an infinite sequence and the `.Aggregate` statement in `MyMethod` is trying to enumerate the whole sequence.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, moving `Take` to `MyMethod` may work:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> MyMethod(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    return source
    .Select(x => new[] { x })
    .Take(2)
    .Aggregate((a, b) => new[] { a.Last() + b.First() });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[MoreEnumerable.Random](http://morelinq.github.io/2.5/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Random_1.htm#!) enumerate an infinite list of random integers, that's why.

You have to replace

```
var values = MoreEnumerable.Random(1, 200);
```

by a finite list:

```
var values = MoreEnumerable.Random(1, 200).Take(100);
```

For reason I do not know yet, the Aggregation seems to take the whole list, despite you put .Take(2) two lines after.

Comment: "For reason I don't know..." Because an aggregation is with respect to the entire sequence, not a subsequence (Take(n) before Aggregate creates a sequence of n which is a new, full sequence). This aggregator happens to be creating a new enumerable, so the Take is on that, but Aggregate won't return until it's source is exhausted... Which is never

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected. I would have fallen into this trap myself, too, because of this improbable behavior.
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-13-aggregate/

Answer (score 0):

I find out that this method(.Random(1, 200)) returns an infinite sequence of random integers using the standard .NET random number generator. [Documentation](http://morelinq.github.io/2.5/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Random.htm)

Comment: I tended to answer the same way, unfortunately, the .Take(2) statement two lines after should retains the whole infinite list to be enumerated. I suspect the Aggregation to be the culprit... I'm stepping this to check.

Comment: Did you try to call Take() after MoreEnumerable.Random(1, 200).Take(2)?